# Why does index.php persists in my URL?

Tags: url, config, admin, index

I've gone through all the steps here to remove index.php https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php

The .htacess file is the default one that came with Craft on install

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

In my config/general.php file I have the setting set explicity..

```
'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'true',
```

I wrote to Arcustech for help with the httpd.conf file as the last step and they said...

> Changing that setting is not something we will update on Arcustech. If you were not already aware, we are a Craft CMS Hosting Partner and removing index.php in Craft URLs works on our servers without that update.
>
> If you tell Craft Support you are hosted with Arcustech the Craft support team will know stuff will work here, so something else is wrong in the setup or .htaccess file. The account is not set up as a Craft Optimized plan (https://www.arcustech.com/managed/craftcms-hosting/) but that does not matter for basic functionality like that in Craft.

I asked to be moved to the Craft Optimized plan, but it doesn't sound like that's an issue.

Any idea what's going on? Somedays it's fine. Today, at the moment, it's not.

Comment: SMH - It was the single quotes around 'true' in the config file. Ugh. Sorry for the noise. I need a vacation or something.

Comment: It happens. :)  Would you mind adding that as an official answer in case it helps someone in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the single quotes around 'true' in the config file :)